# ¿Cómo puedo verificar si un número es un entero?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero comprobar si un número es un entero, pero tengo el problema de que al intentar deducir si ese entero con uno o varios ceros a la izquierda, **sí es un entero**, me lo marca como decimal.

```
from random import randint
def if_integer(string):
    if string[0] == ('-', '+'):
        return string[1:].isdigit()
    else:
        return string.isdigit()

n1, n2 = randint(1, 100), randint(1, 100)
resultado =  (n1 * 100) / n2

print(resultado)
print(if_integer(str(resultado)))
```

Puede imprimir cualquier número que dé la operación `resultado`. Y en el caso de que sea un entero, lo imprime como `12.0`, pero python no puede deducirlo como entero, por el decimal. Y no sé cómo hacer que python pueda leer un decimal (siendo este un entero con un cero después del punto) como entero.

Entonces, ¿cómo puedo deducir si un número es un entero, a pesar de tener un cero o varios ceros (después del punto `.0`), sea leído como entero?

De antemano, agradezco mucho su apoyo. Saludos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema es que `int("1.0")` falla por la mera presencia del punto decimal, incluso si el valor sea expresable como entero.

La manera más corta de revisar si un valor en punto flotante es representable como entero, es compararlo contra `int(valor)`

```
def if_integer(valor):
    return valor == int(valor)
```

Esta función recibe el valor numérico; no es necesaria convertirlo a string para revisarlo, y returna `True` si el valor es expresable como entero.

#### Demo

```
from random import randint

def if_integer(valor):
    return valor == int(valor)

for i in range(10):
    n1, n2 = randint(1, 100), randint(1, 100)
    resultado = (n1 * 100) / n2
    print(resultado, if_integer(resultado))
```

produce:

```
25.714285714285715 False
410.0 True
247.3684210526316 False
168.75 False
250.0 True
88.88888888888889 False
408.3333333333333 False
285.18518518518516 False
8.75 False
59.21052631578947 False

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Los números flotantes como todo en Python, **son una clase** y por tanto tienen métodos. En concreto los `floats` tienen el método `is_integer()` que nos devuelve `True` o `False` dependiendo de si es entero o no. Tu ejemplo quedaría así:

```
from random import randint

n1, n2 = randint(1, 100), randint(1, 100)
resultado =  (n1 * 100) / n2

print(resultado)
print(resultado.is_integer())
```

**Salida**:

```
245.0
True
```